# What environment to use in writing functions

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am beginner of LaTeX, and wondering how to write functions or procedures in pseudocode. Is there any existing environment for that?

Comment: Try the `algorithm2e` package (which you already tagged :-) )

Comment: There's also **algorithmicx**

Comment: what to write in latex... is there any examples?

Comment: LaTeX is about reading [documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms). You should do it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I'm posting a summary of the comments as an answer.

There are several LaTeX packages for typesetting pseudocode. The most prominent are, in no particular order:

- [`algorithms`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)
- [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)
- [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)

The [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package also has an experimental feature called *literate programming* with similar goals.